# How to create series and setup X and Y axis?

Tags: highcharts

I have to make a series as shown in the image.

The Dates and the values are dynamically generating based on the user selection. The Time is in 24 hrs format. Please tell me how can i create the series for this. Also how to put the duration 1 hour for the time value.

Image for Reference:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to give you a complete answer. For start point: You need stacked bar as in this link **http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked** . but first you should start from **http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart** and then go trough these live demos: **http://www.highcharts.com/demo/** Then come back and ask a specific question about specific problem

Comment: Dear Osyan,  thank you for the reply. Please see the series over here http://jsfiddle.net/P87XF/10/    Please let me know how can i show the hour in the X axis in (HH:MM) format. And i want to plot the values in specific color based on the time range. expecting your reply soon

Comment: Hi, Please edit your question with what you said in your previous comment and add your **jsfiddle** to your question. i will answer you soon

Answer (score 0):

In your series data you are using `data: [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 01, 12,11,10)]` you can simply change that to: `data: [90 *60 * 1000] //For 90 Minute`

Here is the [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/P87XF/22/)

If you want to plot other series for other days then you should add categories in xAxies. for example for showing 3 days:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['01/10/2012', '01/11/2012', '01/2/2012']
},
```

And in series-data use equal number of parameters as you have in your categories  for 3 categories:

```
data: [ 50 *60 * 1000, 100 *60 * 1000, 50 *60 * 1000 ]
```

See the [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/P87XF/25/)

Use `formatter` in tooltip to see a correct `hour:minutes` when you hover the series.

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    var ms = this.y;
    var x = ms / 1000;
    var seconds = x % 60;
    x = x / 60;
    var minutes = x % 60;
    x = x / 60;
    var hours = parseInt(x % 24);
    x = (x / 24);
    var days = parseInt(x);
    if(days == 0)
    {
      return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b> ->' + this.x + '<br/>' + hours +':' + minutes;
    } else {
      return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + days + ' Day ' + hours +':' + minutes;
    }
  } 
},
```

See the [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/P87XF/26/)

Comment: Dear Osyan, thank you very much for the help. Exactly the thing i am looking for. You have made my application working now. Thanks a lot.